# "Jagged" rectangle text in emacs

Tags: emacs

Suppose I have something like

```
this
is
text
```

I want to change it to be

```
"this"
"is"
"text"
```

The first quote I can insert simply by making a rectangle and doing `C-x r t`, but the trailing quote I can't add because they aren't all at the same alignment. Is there any way to add something to the end of all selected lines?

Comment: Maybe you'd like [this mode](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el), which is useful for this kind of tasks.

Comment: Related, http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108895/4671

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use `replace-regexp` for this -- replace `$` (end of line) with whatever you want.  You could do it all in one shot by replacing `^.*$` with `"\&"`.